How can I use the concat operator (||) in Sequelize for ilike comparison?
I'm working on an express.js project, using Sequelize on a postgres database, and we have the following query:
SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE first_name || ' ' || last_name ILIKE '%search term%'

I'm using || because it's much faster than the concat function, and we can index it with gin. Is this possible to do in Sequelize without using a raw sql query? I need something like this:
models.Client.findAll({
  where: {
    ["first_name || ' ' || last_name"]: {
      { [Op.iLike]: `%${searchTerm}%` }
    }
  }
})

But that doesn't work, can't find documentation about it either. Keep in mind the original query is much bigger and it's all implemented in Sequelize already, so if I need to do a raw query, I would have to convert that whole query in raw sql.

Please update the post with the text of any reported exceptions. Why is ILIKE in the string literal when Op.ilike is also present?

Edited, it was supposed to be only the left side expression of the ILIKE, I'm updating the post with exceptions later

If you have a problem with the || operator, you can concat strings in alternative ways, e.g. concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name) or format('%s %s', first_name, last_name).

But those are slow in comparison to ||, right? Can I even make a gin index for those functions?

You can try to use Sequelize.where in conjunction with Sequelize.literal

@Daniel - The operator is a bit faster than the functions, but the difference is not critical. You are right about indexing, the functions are not immutable so they cannot be used in indexes.
